# Hiding border from embedded iframes containing a Google map

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe

### Background

Google maps has an default border that I prefer not to be shown on our website for aesthetic reasons.

[image]

### Objective

I want to either get rid of it or hide it.

### Code

So far what I have done was to remove to the default height and width that comes in the embed code. Then added a wrapper that is smaller so that the embed will extend beyond it and not be shown.

In Inspect Element I saw that the border is 1px. But just making the `<iframe>` 2px larger and positioning -1px outside was not enough to remove it. So i ended up doing 102% but it is not as precise as I would like. At this point it is functional and no one would really notice but it is a "temporary workaround"

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div class="map-footer-wrap">
  <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zIn_bb78zyjU.kVqzAS1cS9qg" border="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.map-footer-wrap {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.map-footer-wrap iframe {
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  left: -1%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply using `frameborder="0"` instead of `border="0"` is the trick to make the google maps border disappear.